# React Native and { flex: 1 }

Tags: react-native, flexbox

What is the exact purpose of setting rule `flex: 1` to many React Native components?

Very often I can see this rules applied to different components. Sometimes this rules obviously redundant. Sometimes no obviously, but layout seems working well without it.

So, what exactly this rule suppose to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the component is rendering fine without using `flex: 1` it is obviously not needed. You might as well want to remove the unwanted style. What `flex: 1` does is that it tells the component to occupy as much space as it can.

For example:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#cccccc' }}>
    <Text>Hi</Text>
</View>
```

This will span the whole screen.

However, if you place another View at the same level in the DOM, both of the Views will occupy equal space i.e. the screen will be divided in two parts.

Like this:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#cccccc' }}>
        <Text>View one</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#eaeaea' }}>
        <Text>View two</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

I agree that flexbox is a little bit confusing. But once you get the hang of it, you'll learn how to manipulate the views.

**Edit:** Always wrap child components with a parent component in order to avoid potential runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

For layout React Native uses `flexbox` because `display: flex;` is extremely well-suited for creating responsive layouts across various screen sizes and devices. All the attribute names and values are listed in the [React Native docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/style.html).

In other words, instead of using `display: block` with various `float`s your layout should be created using `flexbox` rules.

Modus Create did a nice tutorial on [Flexbox in React Native](http://moduscreate.com/react-native-layout-system/).

Specifically, that rule:

```
flex: 1
```

is telling the element to grow to fill the available space.